# Querying data linked to a postGIS database

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, mapserver

My project is coming along nicely!   A brief background on my project.  I have a world map that is colored to show the country of origin of the students at a college.  Each color represents the number students (a range).  E.g. any country colored red has 1 to 20 students at the college.   When you click on a country, I was successful in displaying data specific to that country in a pop-up.

Hopefully I can describe what I want to do next....  I want to add the ability to query the map such that the countries that satisfy the query will be highlighted on the map.
So for example, in my html form I enter > 300... click on submit.... England, India and USA are highlighted.  I've figured out that I need to use WFS getFeature but as you can see it's the how that I need help with...

Can anyone direct me to an example of the above or give me some suggestions, I would be most appreciative.

I am using MapSever, PostGIS and Openlayers

Chris

Comment: So you have built a Mapserver WMS and want to highlight certain features (dependent on queries) on the map?

Comment: Yeah!! you hit the nail on the head!!    
Any ideas as to how I can do it?

Comment: I don't get the title. What are you doing with shapefiles? You say you have your data in PostGIS.

Comment: If you are using WMS/WFS then the fact your data is in postgis is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ["Drawing selected features in Mapserver with mapscript"](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/drawing-selected-features-in-mapserver-with-mapscript/) can get you started.

[Mapserver's Querymap feature](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/querymap.html) seems to be another way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it through a wms-service, but Mapserver has the ability to both 
handle a custom sql-query for getting the data ([take a look at the third and fourth example here](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html))

, and you can use [run-time substitution](http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html) to insert some value from the client into that query. I remember I struggled some to get it working because I missed the validation against the datapattern. You can read about that [here](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/map.html?highlight=datapattern).

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: Nicklas: Thanks for the reply... I think I have the MAP and MAPSCRIPT files set up correctly.... My problem is with openlayers...  I don't know how to setup/define the vector layer.  I looked at the various openlayers examples but could get any to work for me... Are there any openlayers examples that uses mapserver I can review??

Comment: @Chris: did you solve this problem. I am struggeling with the same issue in OpenLayers.